# Output to CSV: Change Existing Code to Add "Flag" Column Instead

Tags: python, file-io, csv

The code (reproduced below) reads in a file, does stuff, and outputs a subset of the original file into a new file.  How do I tweak it a little bit, and instead, output everything from the initial file to the output file, but adding a "flag" column, with values of "1" where the row is a row that currently goes to output (the subset of rows that we are most interested in)? The other rows (currently the ones only in the input file) would either have a blank or a "0" in the new "flag" column.

This problem occurs frequently enough for me, that it would save me many hours just to have a general way of doing this.

Would greatly appreciate any help!

```
import csv
inname = "aliases.csv"
outname = "output.csv"

def first_word(value):
    return value.split(" ", 1)[0]

with open(inname, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as infile:
    with open(outname, "w", encoding = "utf-8") as outfile:
      in_csv = csv.reader(infile)
      out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)

      column_names = next(in_csv)
      out_csv.writerow(column_names)

      id_index = column_names.index("id")
      name_index = column_names.index("name")

      try:
          row_1 = next(in_csv)
          written_row = False

          for row_2 in in_csv:
              if first_word(row_1[name_index]) == first_word(row_2[name_index]) and row_1[id_index] != row_2[id_index]:
                  if not written_row:
                      out_csv.writerow(row_1)

                  out_csv.writerow(row_2)
                  written_row = True
              else:
                  written_row = False

              row_1 = row_2
      except StopIteration:
          # No data rows!
          pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use DictReader when writing CSVs, mainly because it is a bit more explicit (which makes things easier for me :) ). Below is a highly stylized version of what you could do. Changes I made include:

- Using `csv.DictReader()` and `csv.DictWriter()` instead of `csv.reader` and `csv.writer`. This differs by using dictionaries to represent the rows instead of lists, meaning that a row would look like `{'column_name': 'value', 'column_name_2': 'value2'}`. This means that every row contains the column header data and can also be treated like a dictionary.
- Using sample column names to show how the reading/writing works. I made a sample CSV that had two columns: `name` and `number`, and then when writing, I did a simple check to see if the `number` value was `> 2`

With that in mind, here is the example:

```
import csv

input_csv = 'aliases.csv'
output_csv = 'output.csv'

def first_word(value):
    return value.split(' ', 1)[0]

with open(input_csv, 'r') as infile:
    # Specify the fieldnames in your aliases CSV
    input_fields = ('name', 'number')

    # Set up the DictReader, which will read the file into an iterable
    # where each row is a {column_name: value} dictionary
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames=input_fields)

    # Now open the output file
    with open(output_csv, 'w') as outfile:
        # Define the new 'flag' field
        output_fields = ('name', 'number', 'flag')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=output_fields)

        # Write the column names (this is a handy convention seen elsewhere on SO)
        writer.writerow(dict((h, h) for h in output_fields))

        # Skip the first row (which is the column headers) and then store the
        # first row dictionary
        next(reader)
        first_row = next(reader)

        # Now begin your iteration through the input, writing all fields as they
        # appear, but using some logic to write the 'flag' field
        # This is where the dictionary comes into play - 'row' is actually a
        # dictionary, so you can use dictionary syntax to assign to it
        for next_row in reader:
            # Set up the variables for your comparison
            first_name = first_word(first_row['name'])
            next_name = first_word(next_row['name'])
            first_id = first_row['number']
            next_id = next_row['number']

            # Compare the current row to the previous row
            if first_name == next_name and first_id != next_id:
                # Here we are adding an element to our row dictionary - 'flag'
                first_row['flag'] = 'Y'
            # Now we write the entire first_row dictionary to the row
            writer.writerow(first_row)

            # Change the reference, just like you did
            first_row = next_row
```

Comment: thanks for your post. This didn't work for me, though. First, I got a syntax error on the line: row['flag'] = 'Y'. As I think about it, it's not a valid operation. Right, I mean we want to add a 'Y' to the "flag" column, but it looks like you're using a list as if it were a dictionary or something like that. I am not sure, but the syntax doesn't work, it only works if I make the assignment operator become an equal operator, and that doesn't make sense. ALso, the writer.writerow(row) statement does not work.

Comment: The other issue here is that I'm not sure that this does what I want it to. There are many other fields in the input file that I want to be in the output file, but my logic comparison is based on certain values in specific columns. The way it looks here, it strikes me that we would just get 3 columns "name" "number" and "flag". Is that right?

Comment: As an addendum, I think the logic of how I want to make this tweak is: add a new column by adding a new entry to the row (which is a Python list) before writing it out. Since we can't modify the input file in-place, we can just create a new file and then replace the old file with the new file. It seems like it should be simple, but I'm not sure how to go about it here, since I didn't create any lists initially...

Comment: ps didn't mean to seem harsh in my first comment. I definitely appreciate the help. I just found it to have a few bugs and wanted to point it out.

Comment: Yeah, I was just using a stylized example (sorry, should have stated that - I'll modify the answer). Basically, I changed the reader/writer that you use (which are as you said, based on lists) to DictReader/DictWriter, which use dictionaries. Therefore, when I say "row['flag'] = 'Y'", it is actually assigning a new value to the row dictionary (which is what you're saying in your third comment, I believe). This will write out the row with the new value. So with your files, you would replace ('name', 'number') with the column names from your input, and do the same with ('name', 'number', 'flag')

Comment: No worries man, it was my bad for not being more clear :) I guess the good news is that this works locally for me, so we can definitely find the middleground somewhere and find you something that saves you the hours of time!

Comment: Thanks man! I'm still a little confused though, where does "row" become a dictionary? Isn't it just the iterator in the for loop? Unless this was part of what you mentioned in regarding to modifying the answer because it's a stylized example? Anyway, I very much look forward to seeing your modification whenever you have a chance.  Thanks again!

Comment: I just made a few changes to the answer that hopefully make it more clear. So when we iterate through a `csv.DictReader()` object, each item (in this case, `row`) is a dictionary. DictWriter uses this dictionary by taking the keys (column names), finding the matching column name in the `fieldnames` parameter, and writing the dictionary value to the CSV in that column. The difference is that instead of a list to represent a row (which is accessed by using a numeric index), we use a dictionary (which is accessed by the actual column name). Does that make sense?

Comment: That's a really helpful answer. That makes a lot of sense.Thank you.Now my only question is how to transfer the logic that I used with the lists to the dictionary. The logical criteria I was using was: if the first string up to the first whitespace in a cell in the "name" column equals the first string up to the first whitespace in a cell directly below the first cell, AND, if the "id" for the first record is not the same as the "id" for the record immediately below it, then flag it. Since we're using a dictionary now, is there an easy way to split the "name" column by string up to whitespace?

Comment: (To any mods, we don't have the reputation to move this to chat).Yep, you can actually use the function you wrote as-is. I am modifying the answer to accomplish what you're looking for. Hope it works for you!

Comment: It's working! I had to update the input_fields and output_fields variables to include every column in the file (plus the output_fields has the "flag" column), but otherwise works like a charm! Thank you thank you thank you! I clicked the "check" mark next to your answer, is there anything else I can do to boost your reputation? If so I will more than happily do it. You're a really good teacher :)

Comment: Haha, no worries bud! Just happy to hear it worked, and happy that you got to learn something new! Good luck with stuff and I'll see you around :)

Comment: Thanks!If you don't mind, I had 1 more quick question.I was going over it again, trying to re-create it from scratch, so hopefully I can do any similar problems that I get in the future by myself. And I realized I didn't really understand the following:next(reader), first_row = next(reader), for next_row in reader:..when you wrote next(reader) and then first_row = next(reader), you were making first_row become the first row of data after the column headers, right? But then how did next_row know to start at the second row of data after the column headers? It works, but I don't think I know how.

Comment: `next()` is related to generators, which gets into a whole new world. In this context (and in the context in which you used it originally), just think of it as moving forward one row in the CSV (when run by itself). When we assign (`first_row = next(reader)`) we are assigning a row dictionary to `first_row` AND advancing the iterator. Take a look at some info on generators to get a much more complete explanation, but they are pretty cool and worth learning (if even just to understand).

Comment: Thanks man. I read some good posts about next() and after rebuilding your code a few times figured out how it was working here.  Thanks again! Look forward to reading more of your posts!